# Unable to follow the NLTK corpus structure

Tags: python, nltk

I'm started with `NLTK` & `Python` but Im really confused with the `NLTK` corpus structure.
For instance

1. Im unable to follow why do we need to append words twice to the nltk.corpus module ,

   wordlist=[w for w in nltk.corpus.words.words('en') if w.islower()]
2. Also the type keeps is different for nltk.corpus.words and nltk.corpus.words.words. Why is it so ?

   type(nltk.corpus)

       nltk.corpus

       type(nltk.corpus.words)

       nltk.corpus.words

       type(nltk.corpus.words.words)

       nltk.corpus.words.words
   C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\nltk_data\\corpora\\words'>>
3. Thirdly,how is one supposed to know that one needs to append words twice to `nltk.corpus` in order to generate a wordlist. I mean what is the difference between calling `nltk.corpus.words` and `nltk.corpus.words.words` ?

Could someone please elaborate. As now its getting difficult to proceed through the third chapter of `NLTK` book.

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple really, `words` is the name of the class instance contained `nltk.corpus`, the relevant code:

`words = LazyCorpusLoader('words', WordListCorpusReader, r'(?!README|\.).*')`

All this is saying is that `words` is an instance of `LazyCorpusLoader`.

So you get `nltk.corpus.words` as a reference to that.

But wait!

If you look at the code for `LazyCorpusLoader`, it also calls `LazyCorpusLoader` with `WordListCorpusReader`.

`WordListCorpusReader` happens to have a method named `words`, it looks like this:

```
def words(self, fileids=None):
    return line_tokenize(self.raw(fileids))
```

And `LazyCorpusLoader` does this `corpus = self.__reader_cls(root, *self.__args, **self.__kwargs)`

Essentially what that does is make `self.__reader__cls` an instance of `WordListCorpusReader` (which has its own words method).

Then it does this:

```
self.__dict__ = corpus.__dict__ 
self.__class__ = corpus.__class__
```

According to the Python docs `__dict__ is the module’s namespace as a dictionary object`. So it is changing the namespace to the namespace of `corpus`. As well, for `__class__` the docs say `__class__ is the instance’s class`, so it also changes the class. So that being the case `nltk.corpus.words.words` refers to the instance method words contained in the instance named `words`. Does that make sense? This code illustrates the same behaviour:

```
class Bar(object):
    def foo(self):
        return "I am a method of Bar"

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, newcls):
        newcls = newcls()
        self.__class__ = newcls.__class__
        self.__dict__ = newcls.__dict__

foo = Foo(Bar)
print foo.foo()
```

Also here are the links to the source so you can see for yourself:

http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus-pysrc.html

http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordlist-pysrc.html#WordListCorpusReader